# Understanding a \@for loop

Tags: macros, loops, latex-base

I'm having trouble with a `\@for` loop. I've got a macro that takes a comma delimited list and puts each element into a row of an array.  When I do this using a `\@for` loop, I get an extra row that I don't understand.  I can manually get rid of it with a negative space, (as in the commented line below) but that can't be the right way to do it, so I must be doing something wrong.  Here's a minimal example.  For comparison, if I construct what I expect the result of the loop to be manually, the extra row doesn't appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fbun}[1]
   {\ensuremath{\left[\begin{array}{c}
      \@for\xx:=#1\do {\text{\xx}\\}
%     \\ [-2.75ex] % why is this required?
      \end{array}\right]}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\left[\begin{array}{c}
      A\\
      B\\
      C\\
      D\\
      \end{array}\right]$
% same array, but generated by a macro
\fbun{A,B,C,D}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Altermundus said, you cannot add extra `{}` or `\relax` or other invisible material after the last row of the `tabular`. However, there is some extra material added after `\@for`. The implementation of `\@for` is not very good for this.

Since the `\@for` in LaTeX2e kernel has restrictions, I suggest `\forcsvlist` from `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\addrow#1{\text{#1}\\}
\newcommand{\fbun}[1]
   {\ensuremath{\left[\begin{array}{c}
      \forcsvlist\addrow{#1}%
      \end{array}\right]}}

\begin{document}
$\left[\begin{array}{c}
      A\\
      B\\
      C\\
      D\\
      \end{array}\right]$

\fbun{A,B,C,D}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

In "User's Guide and Reference Manual" Leslie Lamport writes page 45:

> There must be no `&`after the last item in a row and no `\\` after the last row.

```
$\left[\begin{array}{c}
      A\\
      B\\
      C\\
      D\\{}%
\end{array}\right]$
```

This code gives a new line with an empty group. Each cell of an array is in a group.

`\@for`is a `no developable loop`so you need to write something like

```
\fbun{A,B,C} 
D
```

or you can create a `developable loop` but it's more complicated :

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\For}[1]{\noalign{\gdef\@Do##1{#1}}\@For}
\newcommand*{\@For}[3]{%
  \unless\ifnum#1 \ifnum#3>0 >\else <\fi #2
    \@Do{#1}%
    \expandafter\@For\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+#3}{#2}{#3}%
  \fi
} 
\makeatother

$\left[\begin{array}{c}
  \For{\@Alph{#1}\\}{1}{4}{1}    
\end{array}\right]$
```

`\For` is a `developable loop` for example, you can try :

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \For{A number & #1\\}{1}{20}{1}
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that TeX finds something following the last `\\` which starts a new row (it's neither `\noalign` nor `\crcr` that wouldn't).

A solution might be to use a token register: we develop the loop while in the first cell, so there's no problem of `\xx` not being defined any more after TeX has seen `\\` (or `&`).

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fbun}[1]{%
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \toks@={\@gobble}%
  \@for\next:=#1\do
    {\toks@=\@xp{\the\@xp\toks@\@xp\\\@xp\text\@xp{\next}}}%
  \the\toks@
  \end{bmatrix}}
\makeatother
```

I've used `\@xp` (from **amsmath**) that's a shorthand for `\expandafter`; if the `\text` around the entry wasn't required, then

```
\toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\next}
```

would have sufficed. Initializing `\toks@` to `\@gobble` has the effect that the first `\\` is swallowed.

Instead of `array` I've used `bmatrix` (change it if you like) and, of course, I deleted `\ensuremath` as the first step. :)

### Update 2023

We can make the solution much shorter and understandable with `expl3` tools.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\fbun}{O{c}m}
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \left[
    \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \clist_use:nn { #2 } { \\ }
    \end{tabular}
    \right]
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\left[\begin{array}{c}
      \text{A}\\
      \text{B}\\
      \text{C}\\
      \text{D}\\
      \end{array}\right]$
% same array, but generated by a macro
\fbun{A,B,C,D}
\fbun[l]{Aaa,Bbbbbb,Cc,Dddd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason you're getting a fifth, empty row when generating the column vector via the for-loop is that the fourth element (like the three before it) gets a `\\` affixed to it; this instruction creates a new row which ends up being blank since there's no further content to create.

A (not very elegant) solution would be to redefine `\fbun` to take two arguments, as follows:

```
\newcommand{\fbun}[2]
   {\ensuremath{\left[\begin{array}{c}
      \@for\xx:=#1\do {\text{\xx}\\} #2
      \end{array}\right]}}
```

and to invoke it as

```
\fbun{A,B,C}{D}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought that the final \\ was causing the problem, but I don't understand why the manually created version of the array, which also has the extra \\ doesn't have a fifth row. (As for your workaround, I think I prefer mine. :-))

Comment: I had a look at the definition of the `\@for` command in the LaTeX kernel (file `latex.ltx`, beginning on row 859) to see if I could figure out why the loop form creates an extra row whereas the non-loop form does not. However, I must say I can't penetrate the dense, uncommented code in that file. :-(

Comment: I seem to recall having looked at that code too. :-) Some more puzzles: if the extra row comes from the final \\, why isn't there a blank row between the C and D in your version of the command? Also, if you add an extra \\ after `#2` in your command, you don't get an extra row.

Comment: Your first question: Well, there's a `\\ ` after `C`, then a `D` is inserted as #2, so I don't see why there should be an empty row. (Incidentally, I did try out my code before posting the answer, to be sure there was no longer an extra row...) Re question 2: I can't tell for sure, but presumably it's for the same (and currently unknown/not-yet-understood) reason for why there's no blank row in the non-loop creation of the column vector...

Comment: Right, but by hypothesis, the loop *always* should introduce an extra row at the end of the loop, so it's not clear to me why you shouldn't get two \\'s after the C, since you seem to get two \\'s after my version of the loop.  That's what's so weird about the problem. (BTW, if you try to make the \\'s code the markup gets confused.)

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `\ekvcsvloop` provided by `expkv`. I also added a small key=value interface with `expkv-cs`, the supported keys are `align` and `formatter` (the latter will get the text of each row as argument). There are also a few shortcuts in the key=value interface, `c` is `align=c`, `l` is `align=l`, `r` is `align=r`, and every unknown key without a =value is considered a formatter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fbun[1][]{\fbun@kv{#1}}
% this is the output, if you don't need the bling bling of a key=value interface
% you can reduce the \fbun definition to this.
% With the current definition it'll get two arguments from \fbun@kv and as an
% additional argument reads the comma separated list.
\newcommand\fbun@out[3]
  {%
    \left[\begin{array}{#1}
      % ekvcsvloop will result in `\\#2{<#3-element>}` for each element in the
      % csv-list #3 (thanks to \expanded in a single step), `\@gobble` will
      % remove the first `\\`.
      \expandafter\@gobble\expanded{\ekvcsvloop{\\#2}{#3}}%
    \end{array}\right]%
  }
\ekvcSplitAndForward\fbun@kv\fbun@out
  {
    % the two keys that will correspond to an argument for \fbun@out
     align     = c
    ,formatter = \@firstofone
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\fbun@kv
  {
    % in expkv it is documented behaviour that multiple equals signs are
    % allowed, the first is the one separating key from value
    % `nmeta` defines the following name to be a shortcut to set whatever is
    % specified in the value.
     nmeta c = align=c
    ,nmeta l = align=l
    ,nmeta r = align=r
  }
\ekvdefunknownNoVal{\string\fbun@kv}{\ekvcPass\fbun@kv{formatter}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\fbun[\text]{Abc,B,C,D}$
$\fbun[c,\text]{Abc,B,C,D}$
$\fbun[l,\text]{Abc,B,C,D}$
$\fbun[r,\text]{Abc,B,C,D}$
$\fbun{ab,c,d}$
$\fbun[align=@{}c@{}]{ab,c,d}$
\end{document}
```

[image]