# complex nodes with tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

I am trying to convert my `tree-dvips` trees into something that is compatible with xelatex. I had a look at the `tikz-qtree` package, but it seems to be impossible to set complex nodes.

In the old `qtree` package there was a low level syntax that I could use (leaf, branch, ...), but this seems to be gone. In `tree-dvips` I just put the complex stuff inside of `\node{...}`, but how do I do this with `tikz-qtree`?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

This is some text and the figure should be the size of the text not larger and not smaller.
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
             spr eliste,\\
             comps eliste ]
             \end{tabular}} [.NP dogs ] [.V sleep] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

This is some text and the figure should be the size of the text not larger and not smaller.

\end{document}
```

Edit: Tried to do without the tabular environment, but adding the left/north option gives me a funny result. Look at the "man" in the following figure. It is too much north.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=left, anchor=north}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=3\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=12\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.{V[{\sc comps} { }]}
          [.{{1} NP} man ]
          [.{V[{\sc comps} { {1} }]} 
               [.{{2} NP} ketābāro ]
               [.{V[{\sc comps} { {1}, {2} }]}
                    [.{{3} PP} \edge[roof]; {be Sepide} ]
                    [.{V[{\sc comps} { {1}, {2}, {3} }]} dādam ]
               ]
          ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

This is some text and the figure should be the size of the text not larger and not smaller.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.V [.{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} spr eliste \\ comps eliste \end{tabular}} ] [.N tree ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

This is some text and the figure should be the size of the text not larger and not smaller.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I am really impressed by the speed in which one gets things done with stackexchange! Thanks all of you! My mistake was the missing space before ]. I always thought my complex table was the problem.

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to wrap your complex node in a `tabular` environment.  TikZ allows nodes to contain newlines provided you specify an explicit alignment for the text in the node.

So add the following line to your document:

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=left, anchor=north}}
```

or

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
```

And you don't need to use the tabulars at all.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=left, anchor=north}}
\begin{document}

\Tree [.V [.{[spr eliste \\ comps eliste]} ] [.NP dogs ] [.V sleep ] ] 

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

With respect to your edit, using `anchor=north` isn't appropriate for terminal nodes of the tree if you need the nodes to line up on a baseline.  (I don't usually draw trees this way, so I wasn't thinking much about that.)

You can solve this problem by using:

```
\tikzset{every internal node/.style={align=left, anchor=north}}
```

or

```
\tikzset{every internal node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
```

The `internal node` key targets all the non-terminals in the tree.

Comment: Yes, but then "spr" and "comps" are not aligned. Maybe it is better to add space that corresponds to the width of "[" rather than using the tabular environment.

Comment: Ok.  It wasn't clear from your question whether you were using the tables for alignment or simply to allow line breaks in your node labels. If you need alignment, then the tabular is the way to go.  For this kind of thing, I usually use a macro.  See (the answers to) [Understanding a \@for loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34995/2693) for an example of one that I use.