# Programming with LaTeX -- Add names and characteristics

Tags: macros, programming

I have to do a lot of certificates and I have a list of names, every name has a characteristic (A,B or C). I have designed the whole structure for the certificate and have the 'name' and 'characteristic' in blank.

My question is if it is possible to do something like

```
while (i in list):
 code for structure with line name = i and charactertistic = char[i]
 i+=1
newpage
```

In `LaTeX`, I mean writing the list and their characteristic in the code.

Comment: Using `expl3` this should be easy.

Comment: You should consider reading any of the following: [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764); [What's the difference between the various methods for producing for loops?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140907/5764); [Teach me how to use `\loop`…`\repeat` constructs, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62368/5764); [Understanding a `\@for` loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34995/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I applied something like a hash-table, using `name/characteristics` as a bundled pair and splitting them with a small helper macro, setting the name as a property key and the characteristics as the key value.

The iteration about all keys is done with `\prop_map_inline`.

Some important notes:

- The keys must be unique -- specifying them again will just overwrite the old value.
- The order of appearance is not necessarily the same as the order of specification!

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_felipe_prop_list 

\def\helpercmd#1/#2{%
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_felipe_prop_list {#1} {#2}
}

\newcommand{\fillproplist}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
    \helpercmd ##1 % Splitting!
  }
}


\newcommand{\displaynamecharacteristics}{%
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_felipe_prop_list {%
    \displaynamechar{##1}{##2}% using a specialized display macro
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
% Change the `\displaynamechar` macro at will: #1 -> key name, #2 -> key value
\newcommand{\displaynamechar}[2]{%
  Name = #1 \hfill Characteristics: #2%

}


\begin{document}
\fillproplist{Gandalf/A, Frodo/B, Sauron The Dark Lord/C}

\displaynamecharacteristics
\end{document}
```

[image]