# Linguistic formulae including feature matrices

Tags: linguistics

I need to include linguistic formulae in my documents. The formulae look like this:

<[X  C ]i  ↔ [N, sg]i ↔ [SG[SEM]]i > ≈ <[X  C  əz]j ↔ [N, pl]j ↔ [PL[SEM]j>

The i's and j's should be subscript, and there should be feature matrices under the C's.If the latter is impossible, the next best solution would be to have the matrices as suibscripts next to the C's, provided the features are stacked vertically.

Is this possible? If so, what package should I be using?

Thanks in advance!

Andreusz

Comment: what exactly do you need? could you show us a picture?

Comment: The answers to this question provide good solutions to a macro for feature bundles. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34995/2693